# Is there a way to write a class decorator for rollback purposes?

Tags: python, contextmanager

I wrote a class with a "revert" decorator. The intention is to change class members in the yield, and if any exception occurs to "revert" all changes. :

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.kuku = 'old_value'

    @contextmanager
    def revertible_transaction(self):
        old_self = deepcopy(self)
        try:
            yield
        except Exception as e:
            self = old_self
            raise e

    def change_stuff(self):
        with self.revertible_transaction():
            self.kuku = 'new_value'
            raise Exception
```

I want self.kuku to still be 'old_value' after I run change_stuff(), but it's 'new_value' instead.

Any ideas why this is not working and how to do this properly?

Comment: `self = old_self` doesn't actually modify any objects. Read up about [how assignment works in Python](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can't usefully assign to `self`; you're just changing which object a local name refers to without modifying the original object. You need to explicitly save the state of the object to restore if necessary.

```
@contextmanager
def revertible_transaction(self):
    old_kuku = self.kuku
    try:
        yield
    except Exception:
        self.kuku = old_kuku
        raise
```

Answer (score 0):

`self` in the `revertible_transaction` is just a local variable. It is a different reference from the `self` in `change_stuff`, rebinding it won't change anything else. Even if you passed along the reference (say, by `yield`-ing and assigning with `with ... as ...`, you'd still not replace whatever reference the caller to the `change_stuff()` method has for the instance.

So you can't replace `self` like this. You'll need to replace the *instance attributes*; you can reach these through the `self.__dict__` dictionary, usually:

```
@contextmanager
def revertible_transaction(self):
    old_state = deepcopy(self.__dict__)
    try:
        yield
    except Exception as e:
        self.__dict__ = old_state
        raise e
```

This won't work for classes that use slots, but the code could trivially be extended to then copy all names listed in all `__slots__` class attributes in the MRO.